# Merge two string fields with LINQ into a string array

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have two fields in my dataset `[FirstName]` and `[LastName]`. I get an `System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection` Object with the following query:

```
Dim query = From dt In _dataset.DataTable1
Where TeamName = "The Avangers"
Select dt.FirstName , dt.LastName
```

I am looking for a way to merge the FirstName and LastName to get a StringArray with the following entries:

```
Item(0): "Banner, Bruce"
Item(1): "Stark, Tony"
Item(2): "Rogers, Steve"
...
```

What I did is I performed a separate query for First and LastName so I could use .ToArray on both queries. Afterwards I merged them in a for each loop. Just wanted to ask if there is a faster way to perform that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatenate your `FirstName` and `LastName` in your query and then apply `ToArray` at the end.

```
Select dt.LastName + ", " &  dt.FirstName
```

Comment: I think you mean `Select dt.LastName + ", " + dt.FirstName`

Comment: @DanVerdolino, yes you are right. From the values it seems.

Comment: Just a remark, be careful with the "+" operator with string, it will re-create a new string object at each "+".

It's probably a bit more efficient using 
`String.Concat(dt.LastName, ", ", dt.FirstName)`

Comment: @Gimly, `+` translates to `string.Concat` call, so there is no difference. I am pretty sure about it in C# and I think it is same for VB.Net

Comment: @Habib not that it's very important for that few variables, but wouldn't it translate it to something like 

`string.Concat(dt.LastName, string.Concat(", ", dt.FirstName))` in that case? 
Or the compiler is clever enough to make it into 1 call to string.concat?

Comment: @Gimly, one call to `string.Concat`. This method receives `params` type parameter, where multiple values can be passed to it and in a single statement multiple `+` would translate into `string.Concat(1st,2nd,3rd,...)`

Comment: @Habib +1, but I would suggest using `&` over `+` for string concatenation in VB.NET, short of using `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @DanVerdolino, I didn't know that. I thought `&` is just to make sure that values are indeed string. But both uses `string.Concat` and no `StringBuilder` is involved. Do you have any reference that `&` uses `StringBuilder` ?

Comment: @Habib In VB.NET, `&` is strictly a string operator. While `+` will work with two strings, the compiler has no problem with `string + int`, but that operation will fail at run-time. `Option Strict On` will not allow it to compile. It's more prudent for the developer to "strictly" concat the two items i.e. `string & int.ToString()` anyway. My point is `&` is preferred in VB.NET, while `+` has some dangerous cases in which the dev can make mistakes. Much more info on this by searching `VB.NET & vs +`

Comment: @Habib I take back my comment about the `StringBuilder`, as there are only two strings being concatenated per item selected.

Comment: @DanVerdolino, that is correct, I misunderstood your comment about the `StringBuilder`. :)

Comment: @DanVerdolino It will compile with `+` and Option Strict On if both operands are strings. AFAIK, it was decided to let it work as otherwise it would break too much code.

Comment: @AndrewMorton also because of C# devs working in VB.NET like Habib.